# Python Defining parameters for nested function on outer function call

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function:

```
def splot (self,what):
    df = pd.DataFrame((self.spec[what]).compute()).plot()
    plt.show()
    return df
```

I want to be able to pass [parameters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) to the `.plot()` method when I call the `splot` function, like below:

```
def splot (self,what,arg=None):
    df = pd.DataFrame((self.spec[what]).compute()).plot(arg)
    plt.show()
    return df
```

So when I call `splot`, I give it two arguments: `'what'` (a string), and the arguments I want the plot command to take.

However, this doesn't work: if I pass the argument as a string, I get a `KeyError`, and if not, it throws a variable error. I have a feeling that `*args` should be involved somewhere, but not sure how to use it in this instance.

Comment: Have you called method like this Obj.splot (what, arg="x") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as you are guessing, you have to use the unpacking operator *. Here is an example of code close to yours in order to explain:

```
class myClass:

    def myPlot(self, x=None, y=None):
        print("myPlot:", x)
        print("myPlot:", y)

    def myFunc(self, what, *args, **kwargs):
        print(what)         # 'toto'
        print(args)         # tuple with unnamed (positional) parameters
        print(kwargs)       # dictionary with named (keyword) parameters
        self.myPlot(*args, **kwargs)   # use of * to unpack tuple and ** to unpack dictionary


myObject = myClass()
myObject.myFunc("toto", 4, 12)         # with positional arguments only
myObject.myFunc("toto", x = 4, y = 12) # with keyword arguments only
myObject.myFunc("toto", 4, y = 12)     # with both
```

So you should write your code like this:

```
def splot (self, what, *args, **kwargs):
    df = pd.DataFrame((self.spec[what]).compute()).plot(*args, **kwargs)
    plt.show()
    return df
```

Comment: So that only brings along strings. What I'm trying to do is use the [parameters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) of the       pd.DataFrame.plot command. Is that just use **kwargs instead, or is it more complex?

Comment: @nothingtoseehere OK my first solution worked only with unnamed positional arguments. I have updated my post to work with named arguments either.

Comment: Yep, that works fine. Needs both *args and **kwargs for **kwargs to work for some reason, but it works.

Comment: Cool. if you use only keywords arguments, you don't need `*args`.  Please consider accepting this answer (by clicking on Accept) if it answers your request.